# expressJs - Wait for a promise inside a loop

Tags: node.js, express

Novice question; I need to create a conditional loop which makes a call to the database. The value returned from the promise determines if I should break out of the loop as follows:

```
let id, caged;

do {
    caged = false;

    id = models.Cage.generateId();
    caged = models.Cage.findOne({ where: { dispatchLabelId: id } });

} while( caged );
```

Can anybody please advise how I can structure my code?

Comment: Do you want to execute the db request with the same query every time?

Comment: Apologies, typo in my example. I have updated. I just wish to ensure the generated ID is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using promises and recursive function calls:

```
let getCage = () => {
  return models.Cage
    .generateId()
    .then(id => models.Cage.findOne({ where: { dispatchLabelId: id } }))
    .then(caged => {
      if (caged) {
        return caged;
      }
      return getCage();
    });
}
```

In the case if you can use node.js v7.6 or higher you can avoid using recursive function calls and implement this using `async/await`:

```
let getCage = async () => {
  try {
    do {
      let id = await models.Cage.generateId();
      let caged = await models.Cage.findOne({ where: { dispatchLabelId: id } });
      if (caged) {
        return caged;
      }
    } while (true);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```